# Find min items in each group of array

Tags: java, algorithm

Give an array of numbers of size `n`, pick a group of size `m`, find the `k`th minimum element in that group.

**Example:**

```
arr = [1, 3, 2, 1], m = 3, k = 2
m represents a group size
k represents the kth minimum element in the group of size m
so find the 2nd minimum element in a group of size 3.

There are 2 contiguous groups possible:
[1, 3, 2] and [3, 2, 1]

k = 2 , 2nd minimum element in above groups is [2,2]
```

**Constraints:**

```
k, m , n are of size 1 to 10^5
array item is of size 1 to 10^9
```

Here is my code:

**Approach 1:**
This is my naive approach:

```
public static int[] solve(int[] arr, int m, int k) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = arr.length;
    for(int i=0; i<=n-m; i++) {
       int[] sub = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, i+m);
       Arrays.sort(sub);
       result.add(sub[k-1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This approach is not time efficient so fails for large inputs

**Approach 2:**
Using Queue:

```
public static int[] solve(int[] arr, int m, int k) {
    int n = arr.length;
    int[] result = new int[n - m + 1];
    Queue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b, a));

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        q.add(arr[i]);
        if (q.size() > k) {
            q.poll();
        }
    }
    result[0] = q.peek();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n - m; i++) {
        int left = arr[i - 1];
        if (q.contains(left)) {
            q.remove(left);
        } else {
            q.poll();
        }
        q.add(arr[i+m-1]);
        result[i] = q.peek();
    }

    return result;
}
```

My 2nd approach fails with wrong output when input array size is more. What is the correct approach to solve this?

Comment: If the group `[1, 1, 2]` is selected what is the 2nd largest element, 1 or 2? Are you certain that the array can contain duplicates (as `arr` in your example) and is not sorted?

Comment: If your problem is taken from the internet (e.g., Leetcode or Hackerrank) can you provide the URL? There are some details I don't follow. For example, you have not defined `n`. Is that the size of the array?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I don't have URL of this. yes `n` is array size, I updated my post. [1,1,2] here in this group, first largest is 2, 2nd and 3rd largest are 1, duplicates are allowed in array and input is not sorted.

Comment: I suggest one more change: in the first sentence you replace "pick a group of size m" with something like "pick a group of m contiguous elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given:

- an array of integers `arr`;
- a group size `m`, where groups are comprised of contiguous elements of `arr`; and
- a rank `k`.

The object is to identify the k<sup>th</sup> smallest element of each group selected.

Groups can be selected by identifying their starting index of `arr` (that is, `arr[i], arr[i+1],..., arr[i+m-1]` for given `i`) or by an an array of `m` contiguous elements of `arr` without knowledge of its starting index in `arr`.

Note that if we were only selecting and analyzing a single group the array from which it is drawn, `arr`, would be irrelevant to the question. I therefore assume we are to process a sequence of groups-- possibly many--and for that reason we may invest significant time to the preparation of tools that will speed the processing of groups as they make their way down the assembly line.

I will use limited code but where I do it will be Ruby, which generally can be read as pseudo-code.

---

Suppose we are given

```
arr = [67, 225, 134, 28, 225, 152, 10, 128, 59]
m = 5  # group size
k = 3  # rank order
```

We may compute

```
n = arr.size #=> 8
```

We can say that "group `i`" equals the elements in the range

```
arr[i]..arr[m+i-1]
```

For example, if `i = 1`, group `1` is

```
[225, 134, 28, 225, 152]
```

The k<sup>th</sup> smallest value of each group `i` is seen to be the following.

```
i                 group                    kth smallest
_______________________________________________________
0  [67, 225, 134, 28, 225]                      134
1      [225, 134, 28, 225, 152]                 152 
2           [134, 28, 225, 152, 10]             134
3                [28, 225, 152, 10, 128]        128 
4                    [225, 152, 10, 128, 59]    128
```

We can construct a hash that maps the starting index of each group to the k<sup>th</sup> smallest value as follows.

```
h = {}
(0..n-m).each { |i| h[i] = arr[i, m].sort[k-1] }

h #=> { 0=>134, 1=>152, 2=>134, 3=>128, 4=>128 }
```

(`arr[i, m]` equals an array comprised of the `m` elements of `arr` that begin at index `i` and `arr[i, m].sort[k-1]` extracts the element at index `k-1` of `arr[i, m].sort`.)

This is a relatively inefficient way of computing `h` but I don't want to focus on that. However, I will outline a more efficient method at the end.

Armed with the hash `h` we can easily compute the k<sup>th</sup> smallest value of each group taken from `arr`. Initially assume we know the group's starting index in `arr`:

```
i = 2
group = arr[i, m]
  #=> [134, 28, 225, 152, 10]
```

then `group`'s k<sup>th</sup> smallest value is simply

```
h[i] #=> 134
```

If we are only given the array `group`, and not its starting index in `arr`, we need to find the starting index. One way follows.

```
i = (0..n-1).each_cons(m).find do |indices|
  arr.values_at(*indices) == group
end.first
  #=> 2
```

The k<sup>th</sup> smallest value for this group is therefore

```
h[i] #=> 134
```

Note that

```
(0..4).each_cons(3) { |a| puts a }
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

and if

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
indices = [1, 2, 4]
```

then

```
arr.values_at(*indices)
  #=> arr.values_at(1, 2, 4) => [2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5].first
  #=> 2
```

---

---

Below I outline a more efficient way to compute the hash `h`, which maps indices `i` of `arr` to the k<sup>th</sup> smallest element of the group `arr[i],..., arr[i+m-1]`.

For the earlier example we start with

```
i = 0
```

so<sup>1</sup>

```
group = arr[i, m]
  #=> [225, 134, 28, 225, 152]
```

We may compute

```
sorted = group.sort
  #=> [28, 134, 152, 225, 225]
```

so

```
h[i] = sorted[k-1]
  #=> 134
```

and

```
h #=> { 0=>134 }
```

Now increment `i`.

```
i = i + 1
  #=> 1
```

The group starting at index `i` is computed from the previous group, with one element dropped off and one element added:

```
leaving = group.shift 
  #=> 225
group
  #=> [134, 28, 225, 152]
```

```
arriving = arr[i+m]
  #=> 10
group.push(arriving) # returns group
  #=> [134, 28, 225, 152, 10]
```

We now need to update `sorted`. To do that we use a binary search (O(`log m`)) to determine `j` where

```
leaving = sorted[j]
```

We find that `j #=> 3`, so we remove `sorted[3] #=> 225`, after which

```
sorted
  #=> [28, 134, 152, 225]
```

Next, we again use a binary search, this time to determine where `arriving #=> 10` should be inserted into `sorted`. We find that it should go before the first element of `sorted`, so we obtain

```
sorted
  #=> [10, 28, 134, 152, 225]
```

Since

```
sorted[k-1]
  #=> 134
```

we add the key `i` and value `134` to the hash:

```
h[i] = sorted[k-1]
```

so now

```
h #=> { 0=>134, 1=>152 }
```

We may now increment the index:

```
i = i + 1
  #=> 2
```

and continue as before.

<sup>1. As will be seen, it's not necessary to maintain the array `group`, as its elements can always be computed from the index `i`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you need two priority queues. `q1` is for the smallest `k` elements in the group with the largest at the head of the queue. And `q2` is for the remaining `m-k` with the smallest at the head of the queue. (You do that by having a different `Comparator` for the queues.)

And then your key logic loop looks something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n - m; i++) {
    int left = arr[i - 1];
    if (left <= q1.peek()) {
        q1.remove(left);
        q1.add(q2.poll();
    } else {
        q2.remove(left);
    }
    if (q.contains(left)) {
        q.remove(left);
    } else {
        q.poll();
    }
    q1.add(arr[i+m-1]);
    q2.add(q1.poll());
    result[i] = q1.peek();
}
```

Note that I'd expect `PriorityQueue` to have a `remove` method that is `O(m)`. If that turns out to be true, you won't get good performance until you write your own [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) that keeps track of where the values are. Note that "remove the value at position `x`" can be implemented by swapping the last element with `x`, popping the last element, then letting the value at `x` "sift-down".

Comment: Thank you, what q1, q2 holds initially? because in loop we are trying to access or remove items from queues

Comment: @learner for the startup put first m elements into q2, then move k smallest into q1 (or q1→m-k→q2, either way works)